# Why IPSec ESP needs NAT-T

Tags: vpn, nat, ipsec

I understand why it is not possible to use IPSec AH over a NAT server, since the IP header is included in the MAC too.
But I am confused about ESP with Authentication (I am talking about tunnel mode, but I assume there is no difference to transport mode)

What I got from  [this](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-ipsec.html) explaination is that the authentication in ESP Authenticates the ESP + Payload, including the original IP header, but no fields of the 'new' IP header with is used to get to the other IPSec endpoint.

So why is it a problem if the source address is changing?

I assumed, maybe it is due to changing of the source port, but the source port is encrypted so this won't be the problem.
This lead me to a other possibility, that it is simply not possible to NAT such a packet because there is no port in my IP or ESP header - is that the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This lead me to a other possibility, that it is simply not possible to NAT such a packet because there is no port in my IP or ESP header - is that the reason?

Yes, that's definitely one of the reasons, especially with multiple IPsec hosts behind the same NAT device. Please read [RFC 3715 (IPsec-Network Address Translation (NAT) Compatibility Requirements)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3715) for a description of the potential impact NAT may have on IPsec connections.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! What i get from that RFC is, that ESP does not has the problem with authentication based on the IP (Since IPsec [RFC2406] does not incorporate the IP source and destination addresses in its keyed message integrity check, this issue does not arise for ESP.) as i assumed. Whereas a lot of troubles by NAT itself arise. This RFC helped me a lot!